# RaphaelJS: Creating click-through elements?

Tags: svg, raphael

I need to overlay a label on top of multiple clickable elements. I want to be able to click on an element *through* the label on top of it.

Is this possible? If so, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In [Firefox, Opera and Chrome/Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility) you could use [`pointer-events: none`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) in the style attribute.  I'm not sure how that will work in IE where it's VML rather than SVG, you may have to figure out how to adapt [Forwarding Mouse Events Through Layers](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/) to SVG content.

Comment: Nice one, this is just what I needed