# EventPropogation Raphaeljs

Tags: raphael

Here is the scenario I have.

- There is an image in img tag. There is an svg tag created by Raphael.
- This svg tag is directly under the body tag. svg tag and img tag do
  not share a single parent.  svg overlays on img because of the absolute coordinates on SVG.
- All myshapes are transparent and have event handlers.
- img tag has event handlers.
- When i click, the raphael events are fired but the img event handlers aren't.

How can I enable event propagation from Raphael's SVG to img tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it, I am also linking a couple of very nice posts that talk about this in detail.

[triggering-a-javascript-click-event-at-specific-coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845178/triggering-a-javascript-click-event-at-specific-coordinates)

[forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/)

[raphaeljs-creating-click-through-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620561/raphaeljs-creating-click-through-elements)

```
$('svg').click(function(e){
   var event = new jQuery.Event("click");
   event.pageX = e.pageX;
   event.pageY = e.pageY;
   $("#elem").trigger(event);
   console.log("============");
});
```